# USB Microsoft mouse doesn't work after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: mouse, 14.04

I am using Lenovo X201 running with Ubuntu. After upgrade to 14.04 my Microsoft USB mouse does not work.

```
:~$ lsusb | grep mouse
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
```

It looks like this mouse was detected but don't know why doesn't work (no response). Currently, only IBM trackpoint (touchpad) work. May I know how to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: I am sure this mouse is OK before upgrade to 14.04, also, I try to plug in another mouse. But the result is the same -- doesn't work.

Comment: My USB mouse wouldn't copy/paste/highlight 100%. I switched to PS/2 mouse...no more problems.